# What's the use of matchOptionalTrailingSeparator in Spring Cloud Gateway Predicate

Tags: spring, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-gateway

From the doc about Spring Cloud that Spring.io given:
[image]

> The Path Route Predicate Factory takes two parameters: a list of Spring PathMatcher patterns and an optional flag called matchOptionalTrailingSeparator.

It mentions an optional flag `matchOptionalTrailingSeparator` without more description.

What is the use of this flag and how to use this flag?
Thanks

Comment: if my answer has solved your question then you should upvote and accept the answer so that anyone faces a similar problem knows that the below solution fixed the original problem

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The parameter `matchOptionalTrailingSeparator` is used to determine whether the given Path predicate should also match the requests with the trailing slash `/` too.
By default, the value of this is `true`.

For e.g. below route

```
spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      routes:
      - id: host_route
        uri: https://example.org
        predicates:
        - Path=/foo/{segment}
```

will match both the request `/foo/{segment}` and `/foo/{segment}/`

But if it's written as:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      routes:
      - id: host_route
        uri: https://example.org
        predicates:
        - Path=/foo/{segment},false
```

It will not match the requests with trailing slash `/` i.e. it will only match `/foo/{segment}` and not match `/foo/{segment}/`